# Is a gauge theory from probability normalization $\psi^\dagger \psi$ alone possible? (without derivatives $\overline{\psi} D_\mu\psi$)

Tags: gauge-theory

I am familiar with the gauging process consisting of promoting a global symmetry to a local one, then defining a gauge covariant derivative, and finally using the commutator of the covariant derivatives to find the field.

However, this procedure produces a Lagrangian with contains both the gauge field and the Dirac Lagrangian :

$$
 \mathcal{L}=\overline{\psi} D_\mu \psi -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}
$$

Whereas a pure gauge Lagrangian is

$$
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}
$$

If one is interested merely in the gauge field, is there an equivalent process which goes from $\psi^\dagger\psi$ to $-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$?

That is;

1. is the probability normalization condition $\psi^\dagger\psi$ enough to imply the components of a gauge theory, such as $-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$?

or does one absolutely need the derivative to deduce the gauge:

2. $\overline{\psi} D_\mu \psi$ implies $\overline{\psi} D_\mu \psi -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$

---

I suppose my larger question is : can there be a gauge without a derivative?

Answer (score 2):

The gauge covariant derivative already assumes that there is an interaction between the gauge field an another field. Without the covariant part of the derivative in the kinetic term of the other field there won't be any coupling between the two fields. So the covariant derivative does not "generate" the Lagrangian for the other field.

The Lagrangian of the gauge field by itself is already gauge invariant. So it won't be generated in such a direct process. If you only have the kinetic term of the other field and you make the derivative covariant you don't get the kinetic term of the gauge field. Without the kinetic term the gauge field is not an actual physical field with dynamics. It is just the result of a formal field redefinition.